# Export a polygon from an R plot as a shapefile

Tags: r, export, polygon, shapefile

I have been trying to export the content of a plot (lines/polygons) as a layer/shapefile that I can open in ArcMap. These are some of the libraries that I have been using,

> ```
> library(shapefiles)
> library(PBSmapping)
> library(adehabitatHR)
> library(maptools)
> library(maps)
> library(rgdal)
> library(igraph)
> ```

My lat/long data looks like this:

> ```
> tagdata<-read.table(text="meanlat  meanlong
> -18.63327 147.0248
> -18.6368  147.0238
> -18.62068 147.294
> -18.62953 147.2942
> -18.62953 147.2942
> -18.62091 147.2938
> -18.62953 147.2942
> -18.62466 147.2926
> -18.73393 147.2816
> -18.73393 147.2816
> -18.75383 147.2541
> -18.75383 147.2541
> -18.75383 147.2541
> -18.75383 147.2541
> -18.6368  147.0238
> -18.63063 147.0256
> -18.63063 147.0256
> -18.68133 147.1164
> -18.6368  147.0238
> -18.63063 147.0256
> -18.63063 147.0256
> -18.75383 147.2541
> -18.61273 147.0682
> -18.69655 147.09
> -18.6368  147.0238
> -18.63063 147.0256
> -18.63063 147.0256
> -18.63217 147.0251
> -18.75383 147.2541
> -18.75383 147.2541
> -18.75383 147.2541
> -18.63063 147.0256
> -18.68133 147.1164
> -18.68133 147.1164
> -18.63217 147.0251
> -18.69922 147.0909
> -18.73393 147.2816
> -18.63632 147.0792
> -18.69522 147.0896
> -18.6368  147.0238
> -18.75383 147.2541
> -18.75383 147.2541
> -18.75383 147.2541",header=TRUE)
> ```

I plotted the locations and calculated the Minimum Convex Polygon (MCP) using the AdehabitatHR package.

> ```
> plot(tagdata$meanlong,tagdata$meanlat, col="red",pch=1)                  
>
> loc<-tagdata[ ,c("meanlong","meanlat")]
> coord<-SpatialPoints(loc)
> poly<-mcp(coord,percent=100)
> plot(poly,add=TRUE)
> ```

I know how to export/write points as shapefile that I can open in ArcMap or similar softwares,

For example:

> ```
> loc<-SpatialPoints(loc) # #convert loc to spatial points
> rem<-tagdata[c(-1:-2)] 
> SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords=loc,data=rem) 
> obj<-SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords=loc,data=rem)
> writePointsShape(obj,"myshape.shp")
> ```

However, I haven't found a good way to do it with a polygon o polyline object. I would loke to be able to export/write the poly object with the MCP as a shapefile. Any suggestions?

Comment: [`rgdal` `writeOGR`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/rgdal/docs/writeOGR)

Comment: Obligatory Open Source Evangelism: Why are you using ArcMap? Why not try Quantum GIS? Or if you have further analysis to do, do it all in R!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`rgdal` is superb for this kind of thing. http://www.gdal.org/ has most of the information you could every want on what formats are supported.

In this case you want the  `writeOGR` function

```
# this will create a shapefile called poly within the working directory
library(rgdal)
writeOGR(poly, dsn = '.', layer = 'poly', driver = "ESRI Shapefile")
```

You could just as easily use it to write any shape file (point, polygon etc) but they must be `SpatialxxxDataFrame` objects

```
coorddf <-  SpatialPointsDataFrame(coord, data = data.frame(dummy = rep(1,nrow(coord@coords))))
writeOGR(coorddf, dsn = '.', layer = 'mypoints', driver = "ESRI Shapefile")
```

Comment: So how can I convert my Ploy<-MCP "object" that I plotted into SpatialxxxDataFrame. I know how to do it with points, but how can I do it with objects that don't really have a clear spatial reference?

Comment: Add an  example of what you mean within your question

Comment: Your object `poly` is a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`

Comment: By SpatialxxxDataFrame i mean SpatialPointsDataFrame , SpatialPolygonsDataFrame or similar

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot! I was not sure if I need it an X/Y attribute table link to my polygon to export it as a shapefile.